# TensorFlow: tf.summary.text and linebreaks

Tags: text, tensorflow, summary, tensorboard

How do you use tf.summary.text to emit text that contains linebreaks?

I have tried replacing `'\n'` with `<br>` but I cannot get the output to show proper linebreaks. Without proper linebreaks makes it very hard to read yaml output as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Tensorboard `text` uses the markdown format (though it doesn't support all its features). That means you need to add 2 spaces before `\n` to produce a linebreak, e.g. `line_1  \nline_2  \nline_3`

Answer (score 2):

Use \n\n. It produces too much line break though.

Answer (score 2):

I had been encountering the same issue, so I will answer here what I found ( I put this in the issue as well).

For me I cared specifically about tables and regardless of line break type `\n` or `\r\n` ( or double space for that matter) it results in the same line-ending-less output.

```
| heading | heading | |--- |--- | | key | value | | key | value |
```

I entirely missed the part about `2d tensors will be rendered as tables` but the following does create a table:

```
tl = [
    ["**key**","**value**"],
    ["key_2","`value_2`"],
    ["key_3","value_3"]
]
tfboard.add_summary(sess.run(tf.summary.text("eh1", tf.convert_to_tensor(tl))))
```

So it looks like all newlines are just stripped from single strings and if you want consecutive lines, try making a table as a list.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to dump a pandas DataFrame, use [to_markdown()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text):

> The standard TensorBoard Text Dashboard will render markdown in the
>   strings, and will .....

So you need to provide strings as you would provide them for markdown (`<br>` and `\n` do not work in markdown so they do not work here as well).

Comment: The documentation for Markdown says: 
`When you do want to insert a <br /> break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.`
That also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug on TensorBoard. Please file an issue on our GitHub (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues) with a simple gist that will reproduce it, and we'll figure out what's going on and make sure it's fixed.