# Formula labels in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, latex, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, tex

Is it possible to write the scalar labels in TensorBoard as mathematical expressions? (e.g. with Tex, Latex etc.).

Something like

```py
tf.summary.scalar('$f^2$', ...)
```

I want to make the output labels look nice on TensorBoard.

Comment: Ok. It doesn't *look* like it's mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras), though from other digging, it seems `tf.summary.text` supports [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016458/tensorflow-tf-summary-text-and-linebreaks). If `scalar` also does, then `<sup>2</sup>` may do it. If not, are you allowed to use `scalar` with `summary`? Perhaps you can give it a good name, then use the `text` property to describe it with markdown.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance, thanks for the tip, according to [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions) I have tried
`tf.summary.text("1", "$\sqrt{x+1}$", step=0)
tf.summary.text("2", "$$\sqrt{x+1}$$", step=0)
tf.summary.text("3", r"$\sqrt{x+1}$", step=0)
tf.summary.text("4", r"$$\sqrt{x+1}$$", step=0)
tf.summary.text("5", r"```math \sqrt{x+1}```", step=0)
tf.summary.text("6", "```math \sqrt{x+1}```", step=0)`
and none of them worked so I am guessing its supported for now

Comment: Oh, yeah. Unless they specifically use MathJax in their markdown rendering, that's not going to work. UTF-8 characters may be the way to go with symbols. Maybe it's worth putting in a feature request for?